# How to avoid Chrome "Save as PDF" encoding "fi" etc. as ligatures?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

In Chrome, I use Save as PDF on this page https://www.lawgazette.co.uk/benchmarks/calculation-of-time/5041273.article .

I expect the "fi" in "five" to be encoded as f i v e.

What I get is apparently a ligature.

[image]

(PDF X-Change Editor confirms a single character, but due apparently to a bug in Content pane, fails to render it.)

This prangs e.g. search.

What's the solution?

PS Firefox does the same:

[image]

albeit that the PDF X-Change Editor display fail differs.

Comment: This is likely to be a function of the web page having a separate print stylesheet.

Comment: So using Inspect to first delete the print stylesheet would solve it, right? Sadly it doesn't.

Comment: Not necessarily - I don't know if it does work this way, but I've thought I had reason to believe that it actually re-retrieves the page to render it for printing.

Comment: "it actually re-retrieves the page to render it for printing." Sounds credible. Then damn. I guess I'd have to resort to e.g. a tricky greasemonkey script. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unknown when or if the bug has been closed but issue persists as follows, currently using Chromium based Edge that character pair at source is not a ligature but distinctly separate characters. (In fact printing this StackExchange page with its CSS does not seem to generate ligatures).

Here focusing on the print preview and also the page print in progress and then result as seen in exchange

[image]

[image]

What we can see is if I deliberately separate the `f` from the `i` that character is distinct as seen on the left extraction HOWEVER the pair on the right that were converted by use of the imbedded font after print preview were conjoined as a ligature, thus it seems it is a setting in chrome that may need to be set to not apply ligatures in some fonts during conversion (some print editors do have such a setting).

Overall its not a bug as such since the specific "Font" encourages ligatures, and modern browsers default to using them!. However there does not seem to be a user preference exposed for applying an over-ride at print time.

### There is a bookmarklet "hack"

as seen working here where the print now has only `f` (and i) **NOTE** the "favorite NoLigatures" in top left corner

[image]

What it requires is the bookmarks be visible (seems not to work when hidden)
it injects a `font-feature-settings: "liga" 0!important;` before invoking print()

and for ease of cut  and paste I used the one from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55000505/10802527 as posted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/9867895/lovestackh343

Answer (score 1):

This is an old bug in Chrome that dates from 2011.
Today it even disappeared from `code.google.com`, but is still to be found
in the Wayback Machine:
[Issue 80996:   PDF fonts not displaying correctly (ligatures)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130525224214/http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80996).

The bug was discussed until 2013 and was claimed to be fixed.
Apparently the fix has somehow been lost or neutralized in Chrome,
so that the bug has returned.

You should signal the bug as a new bug-report in the Chrome forums.
In the meantime you could use another browser, as it seems that
Chrome is the only one that has this problem.

Comment: "you could use another browser, as it seems that Chrome is the only one that has this problem." But Firefox does the same.

Comment: "You should signal the bug as a new bug-report in the Chrome forums." Thanks, but I'll leave that to someone better qualified inc. with regard to why instead the original report should not be reopened,

Comment: "Issue 80996: PDF fonts not displaying correctly (ligatures)" That's a distinct issue - display of PDF. Mine is in generation of PDF.

Comment: (1) Firefox in my experience doesn't do that - tested again just now. (2) In order to display a PDF, one has first to generate it, not so?

Comment: " tested again just now." Meaning verified again just now?

Comment: "In order to display a PDF, one has first to generate it, not so?" Not so. One can get it from someone else.

Comment: @ChrisJJ:  Yes, I tested Firefox with your link and there was no problem. Also, Chrome generates the PDF with ligatures instead of ASCII characters. This is a bug, no matter where the PDF was generated.

Comment: " I tested Firefox with your link and there was no problem." Thanks. What command? Because here Firefox Save as PDF fails.

Comment: "This is a bug, no matter where the PDF was generated." Agreed. But regardless, it isn't the bug reported in your cited report.